# How do I simulate a higher resolution than native in Wine?

Tags: wine, games, display-resolution

I am using a kind of old laptop with XGA resolution. I have found a tool called newrez that allows me to simulate a higher resolution thus allowing me to see more content in the desktop, file manager, browser, etc. However this script doesn't work with wine apparently, and when running something such as a game using wine it will only allow me to run it at XGA resolution at most. This results in the game using only partial space of the screen with the rest being left unused by the game. Here's a picture of my native resolution vs a higher simulated resolution and an example of what happens when I run a game.

[default resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSN85.png) |
[simulated resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vVJ0.jpg) |
(Chek the comment below to see the example game.. I am not allowed to put more than 2 links)

Any tips on how to get this working? Thanks a lot!

Comment: [example game](https://s9.postimg.org/6szprxjgv/Captura_de_pantalla_de_2016_08_20_16_37_34.png)

Comment: Ok I got this sort of working. I went into wine settings and under the graphics tab I ticked the "simulate desktop" option. Then I entered the desired resolution and now when I run the game it runs in a windowed virtual desktop of a higher resolution than my screen. When used in companion with newrez I am able to see the full window and effectively simulate a higher resolution screen. The only problem now is that I can't figure out how to make the game run in full screen rather than a windows, but at least the original problem is effectively solved.